# jQuery fade on background

Tags: jquery, fade

I have this code

```
 <div id="pic2" style="height:288px;background-repeat:no-repeat"  >
      <div id="pic" style="height:288px;background-repeat:no-repeat"  ><center>Please<br>This<br>Not Follow the Fade<br>Just Static</center></div>
</div>
```

detail here :

http://jsfiddle.net/UC9d6/

I do not want the text inside the div to follow the JQuery fade.

thanks for help

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UC9d6/1/?

Answer (score 0):

Put the text in another div and absolutely position it.

```
<div class="relative">
    <div class="fadein">
        <img src="http://workshop.rs/projects/jqfancytransitions/zakynthos_ivan_jekic.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://workshop.rs/projects/jqfancytransitions/blue_window_igor_srdanovic.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="absolute static-text">
         Text goes here
    </div>
</div>


$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2000)
         .next('img').fadeIn(2000)
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
      4000);
});


.fadein { position:relative; width:500px; height:332px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }

.relative {
    position: relative;
}

.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

.static-text {
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LHSRh/1/